# How to partition by without using changing column

Tags: group-by, ranking, row-number, dense-rank, partition-by

SELECT column1, column2, column3
from(
SELECT column1, column2, column3,
row_number() over (
partition BY column1, column2
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN column3 = 'N/A' THEN 999999999
ELSE
to_number(column3) END ) rn
FROM table1)
WHERE rn = 1

if OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#mytable) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE
END

create table #mytable(
PN varchar(10)
GN int
LN int
NM varchar (5)
PR int
)

INSERT INTO #MYTABLE VALUES ('ABC123', 0, 1, 'GA' 10)
INSERT INTO #MYTABLE VALUES ('ABC123', 1, 1, 'TX' 10)
INSERT INTO #MYTABLE VALUES ('ABC123', 2, 1, 'GA' 10)
INSERT INTO #MYTABLE VALUES ('ABC123', 3, 2, 'CA' 10)
INSERT INTO #MYTABLE VALUES ('ABC123', 4, 1, 'GA' 10)
INSERT INTO #MYTABLE VALUES ('ABC123', 4, 2, 'NY' 10)
INSERT INTO #MYTABLE VALUES ('ABC123', 5, 1, 'GA' 10)

### Row PN   GN     LN     NM      PR

1   ABC123  0   1   GA  10
2   ABC123  1   1   TX  10
3   ABC123  2   1   GA  10
4   ABC123  3   2   CA  10
5   ABC123  4   1   GA  10
6   ABC123  4   2   NY  10
7   ABC123  5   1   GA  10

with cte as
(select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MT.PN,MT.LN,MT.NM,MT.PR
ORDER BY MT.PN,MT.GN,MT.LN) RN
FROM (SELECT * FROM #MYTABLE) MT)
SELECT CTE.* FROM CTE WHERE RN=1 ORDER BY PN,GN,LN

### O/P
Row PN  GN  LN  NM  PR

1   ABC123  0   1   GA  10
2   ABC123  1   1   TX  10
4   ABC123  3   2   CA  10
6   ABC123  4   2   NY  10

EXPECTED:
Row PN  GN  LN  NM  PR

1   ABC123  0   1   GA  10
2   ABC123  1   1   TX  10
3   ABC123  2   1   GA  10
4   ABC123  3   2   CA  10
6   ABC123  4   2   NY  10

Expected row 3 is missing because of not using column GN. Requirement is , I need to populate only the rows based on GN. if latest GN row is already having duplicate LN, NM, PR, I need to populate only the first occurrence of LN,NM,PR combination.